# binding a class with arguments in constructor in AbstractBinder

Tags: java, jersey, hk2

I have a class Test.
I created a class called TestBinder which extends AbstractBinder and does the binding. Here the constructor of Test has no arguments.

```
@Provider
public class TestBinder extends AbstractBinder
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        bind(Test.class).to(Test.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

Now if Test has a constructor with arguments, how will the configure change ?

Comment: If constructor is marked with @Inject, you could bind its parameters in TestBinder, and they will be injected in runtime to Test constructor in order to create Test instance.